# jqxBarGauge background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

I am building a simple webpage with a `jqxBarGauge` on it. The gauge is within the body which has a background color (grey) specified via `css`. Is there any way to get the `canvas` color to match the `background` color? In my photo, I want the white to be grey.

Do you have any ideas, please?

[image]

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxbargauge/index.htm#demos/jqxbargauge/defaultfunctionality.htm I'm guessing the `backgroundColor` property may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Already tried. That property seems to change the background of the bar areas, not the whole widget.